# Why do we need independence to show the density function of X+Y is the convolution of the densities of X and Y?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I'm trying to show that if $X,Y$ are continuous independent RV's with densities $f_X$ and $f_Y$, then $f_{X+Y} = (f_X*f_Y)$.

I'm clearly doing something stupid here, since my 'proof' doesn't use independence anywhere that I can see.  I think I'm incorrectly applying the FTC perhaps?  This is what I have.

Notice that $$F_{X+Y}(t) = P(X+Y \leq t) = P(X \leq t-Y) = F_X(t-Y) = \int_{-\infty}^{t-Y} f_X(x) \: dx$$   Thus, we see by the Fundamental theorem of Calculus: $$\frac{d}{dt} F_{X+Y}(t) = \frac{d}{dt}F_X(t-Y) \implies f_{X+Y}(t) = f_X(t-Y) \: \: \textbf{(1)}.$$ Thus, multiplying both sides by $f_Y(y)$ and integrating over $\mathbb{R}$ with respect to $y$ yields: $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{X+Y}(t)f_Y(y) \: dy = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_X(t-y)f_Y(y) \: dy \implies f_{X+Y}(t) = (f_X*f_Y)(t)$$ using the fact that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_Y(y) \: dy = 1$.

Perhaps this proof is correct, and the independence is implicitly used in $\textbf{(1)}$, where if $Y$ depended on $X$, then $Y \leq t-X$ implies $Y$ depends on $t$, and hence $\frac{d}{dt}F_X(t-Y) = f_X(t-Y)(1-Y'(t))$?

Comment: you do that implicitely , by separating $f_X (x)$

Comment: @GCab Could you explain where I separated f_x?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistaken on the first equation, remember that
$$P((X,Y)\in C) = \iint_{(X,Y)\in C}f(x,y)dxdy$$
where $f(x,y)$ is the joint probability density function of $X$ and $Y$. Then you are integrating over $C=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x+y\le t\}$, so
$$F_{X+Y}(t)=P(X<t-Y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^{t-y}f(x,y)dxdy = \int_{-\infty}^\infty F_{X}(t-y)f_Y(y)dy$$
after applying independency property and integrating over $x$ at the last step.